# PyQt internationalization

Tags: python, qt, internationalization, pyqt

I can transalate texts that comes from QtDesigner, but I can't translate anything that is defined outside it.

In example this code:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QCoreApplication
tr = QCoreApplication.translate


class Flag(object):

    def __init__(self, name):

        self._name = name
        self._setting_events = []
        self._clearing_events = []
        self._toggle_events = []
        self._true_name = tr("Flags", u'True')
        self._false_name = tr("Flags", u'False')
```

According to [documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qcoreapplication.html#translate) first parameter is *context* and second is *sourceText*. But when I open my `.ts` file in QtLinguist, it shows that *context* is my *sourceText* and *sourceText* is a comment. Whatever, after translating it in QtLinguist I release `.qm` files and I run my app, but texts does not change. I see only passed *sourceText*, so in this example it's still `'True'` and not what I translated.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You need to load a translator before the translation function will work.  You do that with code like the following:

```
translationFile = "<langfile>.qm"
translator = QtCore.QTranslator()
translator.load(translationFile, "<filepath>")
a.installTranslator(translator)
```

The `a` is the "app" object, which you create with code such as:

```
a = QtGui.qApp.instance()
```

This is generally done in the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block of your main Python file.

Comment: I actually wrote that translations of string from QtDesigner works, and they wouldn't if I would not load translation file. So I of course loaded it. Anyway, thanks for efforts.

Comment: I think what might be happening is that pylupdate is confused by the reassignment of tr().  I suspect it thinks tr(...) is referring to QObject.tr(), in which the parameters are reversed from those in QCoreApplication.translate().  I tried this myself, and found that if I used QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate() instead of tr(), it worked.  Also, in this case, pylupdate chokes on the u'...' notation.  I found that just using '...' works.

Answer (score 1):

I just fell in the same trap. piccy's comment above says it all.

pylupdate is "just" a file parser. It searches for `tr()` and `translate()` as strings. It ignores affectations such as `my_tr_func = translate`.

If you write

```
my_tr_func = translate
text = my_tr_func("Context", "Source text")
```

your string will be ignored.

The trick here is that you used tr() as an alias, not just any string, and instead of just ignoring it, pylupdate mistook it for the QObject tr() method and parsed its arguments accordingly.

There's nothing much you can do against this (unless you patch pylupdate...).

Note that apparently, you can write

```
translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
text = translate("Context", "Source text")
```

which is better than nothing.

Comment: I can't comment under piccy's comment (not enough rep). Regarding the `u'...'` issue, I struggled a bit with encodings, and the answer I got [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28962869/pyqt4-non-ascii-character-detected-in-trutf8-string) was quite helpful. Now I use `tr()` all the time (I don't use `trUtf8()`), I don't prefix my strings with `u`, I just specify the encoding globally in the .pro file with `CODECFORTR = UTF-8`.

Comment: It might be obvious to you but worth mentioning that in your simplified example, you could also have `Flag` inherit from `QObject` and have the `tr()` method.

Comment: So long as you're using a recent version of pyqt, it's okay to use `u`, because all python string prefixes will be ignored by the parser. Also note that you can specify aliases for `tr`, `trUtf8` and `translate` via the command-line options (do `pylupdate -help` to see the exact syntax).