# How to make a PYQT Graphical User Interface in two different languages?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

I am having a GUI created with pyqt and now i would like to provide the user the possibility of two different languages, english and spanish.

I guess to change the ui into a different language will be easy, but there are a lot of "QMessagebox" which are written manually in english.

Anyone has an idea how to do that?

Comment: This is too broad a question for SO, but the topic you should be searching for is "localization". See e.g. http://plashless.wordpress.com/2014/02/01/internationalizing-python-pyqt-apps/

Comment: Search function `tr()` in PyQt - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14715015/pyqt-internationalization

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think the easiest way for a small program is storing everything in a text file looking like that :

```
firstmessage=message
secondemessage=message
```

Then creating a reader fonction like :

```
def read (text):
 f=open(text,'r')
 h=f.readlines()
 H={}
 for i in range (0,len(f)) :
  h[i]=h[i].split('=')
  h[i]=h[i][1]
  h[i]=h[i].split('\n')
  h[i]=h[i][0]
return H
```

This will return a dictionary looking like associating "firstmessage" with "message" and the rest...
Then you create a parameter window where you can choose your language and the program will reload the dictionary containing the words.