# PyQt4: Non-ASCII character detected in trUtf8 string

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8, qt4, pyqt4

I'm trying to figure out how to feed the PyQt `tr()` or `trUtf8()` functions UTF-8 text.

Here are examples strings:

```
self.tr('λληνικά')
self.tr(u'εληνικά')
self.tr('ελνικά'.encode('utf-8'))
self.tr(u'ελληικά'.encode('utf-8'))
self.trUtf8('λληνικ')
self.trUtf8(u'εληνιά')
self.trUtf8('ελνι'.encode('utf-8'))
self.trUtf8(u'ελλκά'.encode('utf-8'))
```

The ones with `self.tr` display as gibberish in Qt Linguist. The ones with `self.trUtf8` display fine, but they trigger a warning when applying `pylupdate4`:

```
Non-ASCII character detected in trUtf8 string
```

The leading u and the `.encode('utf-8')` don't seem to make any difference, at least at parsing time (using `pylupdate4`).

What is the correct way to proceed ?

I'm also wondering about the role of this line:

```
QtCore.QTextCodec.setCodecForTr(QtCore.QTextCodec.codecForName("utf-8"))
```

But I know it has no effect on file parsing by `pylupdate4`, it could only make a difference at execution time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between `tr` and `trUtf8`, is that the latter explicitly declares that the encoding is `UTF-8`.

On its own, `tr` implies nothing about the encoding of the string, and so you either must only ever pass it ascii strings, or explicitly set an appropriate encoding using `setCodecForTr`. But as you surmised, that will only have an effect at runtime. In order for `pylupdate` to also use that encoding, you need to set a corresponding variable in the pro file:

```
CODECFORTR = UTF-8
SOURCES = source.py
TRANSLATIONS = translation.ts
```

(It seems that `pylupdate` will assume a `latin-1` encoding without that, so any characters not available in that encoding will end up as mojibake).

As for the warnings messages: they are probably there to reflect the corresponding warnings in the [Qt docs for trUtf8](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#trUtf8) regarding portability issues.

The best way to proceeed is to use `tr` and explicitly set the encoding to `UTF-8`. The `trUtf8` function is effectively obsolete in Qt4. It doesn't even exist in Qt5, which assumes `UTF-8` for everything - so eventually you won't even need to explicitly set the encoding.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. I had most pieces of the puzzle already but couldn't get them to fit together.

Comment: Your answer is conform to [this one](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/46300-Manage-japanese-charanters-inside-QPlainText) in the Qt forums. `CODECFORTR = UTF-8` in .pro file and simple `tr('ελληνικά')` in source files works fine. For the record, the encoding specified (this way or using `trUtf8()`) is used for new strings but ignored when updating existing strings (former encoding is used). Keep this in mind when specifying default encoding for an existing project. Create a new .ts file from scratch, then retranslate it, or better, merge it with the old one to keep translated strings.

Comment: I'm not sur I was clear. Let me elaborate as it can be misleading when doing some tests. Without `CODECFORTR = UTF-8`, if you create a string like tr('ελληνικά'), you get mojibake. Changing for trUtf8('ελληνικά') doesn't help if you don't modify the string. It is not updated, neither is its encoding. Conversely, if it is declared with trUtf8('ελληνικά') first, changing to tr('ελληνικά') won't bring any issue unless the .ts file is regenerated from scratch.